# Use __wrap_malloc in a shared library

Tags: c

I created a shared library in Linux that calls malloc wrapper which is the __wrap_malloc.

```
void * __wrap_malloc( size_t size )
{
   printf("Test\n");
   return __real_malloc( size );
}
```

Then the shared library was generated successfully.

But when I use the shared library and build the application. The linker gives me "undefined" error message,

```
undefined reference to `__wrap_malloc'
```

Is is possible to call __wrap_malloc() function in a shared library?

Please advice.

Many thanks.

Comment: Are you on AIX by any chance?  If not, which platform?

Comment: I'm sorry. I'm in Linux platform. thanks

Comment: Show us how you compile/link the shared library and the application that uses it

Answer (score 0):

You are probably not using the --wrap option to ld correctly. Without more information about what command line you were using it is impossible to determine what was going wrong.